# SharePoint Bulk Meta Data changes and Content Approval

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, metadata, content, content-approval

I am in the process of bulk updating meta data for several hundred document in a document library which has content approval (with a workflow) enabled on it.  I have done bulk meta data changes on libraries several times with no problems.  The problem with this library is that it starts the approval process and workflow which sends out emails to company employees when any meta data is changed.

Is there a way to change meta data without triggering the content approval?

I could temporarily disable content approval on the document library while making the changes.  My fear is that dissabling and reenabling content approval may have some sort of negative effect on the documents in the library.  I want to make sure it wouldn't affect version history or workflow history for the documents.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.